# how do i set up firefox/tor searches to be the MOST UNCENSORED AND UNFILTERED

Tags: configuration

Before I installed Tor, I tried to set the about:config menu in firefox to be rid of google. If I receive an answer, please observe that I am a super beginner without an inclination for programming. I need simple instructions like the installation instructions on torproject.org. Anyways, now all the google permissions and interference is back after downloading Tor and it seems the results are censored and filtered and mostly a waste of time. Please can you direct me to configure with the goal of an uncensored and direct search experience....Like Google used to be ten years ago. What search engine should I use and how can I make sure no other entities are interfering?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a verifieably uncensored search engine, you'd probably have to build it your own.

However there are some alternatives:

- [Searx](https://github.com/asciimoo/searx) (Open source meta search engine)
- [Findx](https://www.findx.com/) by Privacore (Open source search engine)
- [Duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com) - alternatively as [hidden service](https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion) (Privacy respecting search engine with a large set of instant answers)
- [Startpage](https://startpage.com) (Privacy respecting search engine that uses the search results from Google)
- ...

There are surely more privacy respecting search engine alternatives to Google. These listed here are just a small percentage of all privacy repsecting searche engines.

---

**How can you make sure no other entities are interfering with your search results:**

- Make sure you use `https` when connecting to a search engine (This prevents an attacker to modify the search results on their way from the search engine to you)
- Use a self hostable alternative (like privx or searx*).

---

*Since search results are retrieved from other search engines certain websites may be still censored.